# Grep: Repeat Line Number for Multiple Matches

Tags: macos, unix, grep

Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do.

```
echo "1234567" | grep -inoE "12|34|56"
```

The above command gives the following output:

```
1:12
34 
56
```

Meaning it found 3 matches on line 1: 12, 34, and 56.

However, I would like the output to show the number on each line:

```
1:12
1:34
1:56
```

I'm using grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: to me, it shows the 2nd format. `grep (GNU grep) 2.21`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm on mac, and using BSD grep. I've updated the question.

Comment: so probably the best solution is to use GNU grep : ) Otherwise, some kind of postprocessing with `awk` would be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `BSD grep` instead of `GNU grep`, this does not work.

I suggest you to pipe the result to a little `awk` that does the remapping:

```
awk -F: 'NF==2{line=$1} NF==1{$0=line FS $0}1' a
```

This stores the line number in a `line` variable and prepends it on the output of the "orphan" lines.

If the match itself contains some colons it will need some extra massaging, so let us know if this is the case.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
1:12
34 
56
$ awk -F: 'NF==2{line=$1} NF==1{$0=line FS $0}1' a
1:12
1:34 
1:56
```